# navigation open and close animation in javascript and css only

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a button to open menu click the button  it content show fast and background move slowly my html code here

```js
function navOpen() {
  let navi = document.getElementById("Nav");

  if (getComputedStyle(navi, null).display === "none") {
    navi.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    navi.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.nav {
  min-height: 1.125rem;
  max-height: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  display: none;
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  background: rgb(167, 165, 165);
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 3.125rem
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="navbutton" onclick="navOpen()">Menu</button>
<nav class="nav" id="Nav">
  <div class="nav_cls" id="nav-btn-cls">
    <a href="#" onclick="navigationClose()">
      <img class="navigation__close_button" src="/images/close.svg" alt="close">
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav_y">
    <li>
      <a class="navlinks" href="#">
        <span>Home </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

here i try to animate use css but the menu content show fast and the back ground color show shlowly and gerkking ,how to aminate menu open and close animation using css and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function navOpen() {
  let navi = document.getElementById("Nav");

  if (!navi.classList.contains("colps-active")) {
      navi.classList.add("colps-active");
  }
}

function navigationClose() {
  let navicls = document.getElementById("Nav");

  if (navicls.classList.contains("colps-active")) {
      navicls.classList.remove("colps-active");
  }
}
```

```css
.colps {
  transform-origin: top;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.colps-active {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.nav {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  background: rgb(167, 165, 165);
}
```

```html
<button class="navbutton" onclick="navOpen()">Menu</button>
<nav class="nav colps" id="Nav">
  <div class="nav_cls" id="nav-btn-cls">
    <a href="#" onclick="navigationClose()">
      <img class="navigation__close_button" src="/images/close.svg" alt="close">
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav_y">
    <li>
      <a class="navlinks" href="#">
        <span>Home </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @andrew ghosh You can change transition time way you want.